# How to make horizontal timeline slider right oriented

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

In horizontal timeline slider jquery, I want that by default it is right oriented. Like in picture now 2015 prices is on right. I want that most right which is 2017 prices is selected by default and user can scroll to left

[image]

My code

```
$('.timeLine-slider').slick({
 dots: true,
 infinite: false,
 speed: 300,
 slidesToShow: 4,
 slidesToScroll: 4,

});
```

Comment: I can't see any code

Comment: updated..........

Comment: Please provide css and html also

Comment: use initialSlide and rtl attribute of slick slider

Comment: please give any example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `initialSlide` option.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.timeLine-slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 4,
    initialSlide: 4
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="timeLine-slider">
  <div>2010</div>
  <div>2011</div>
  <div>2012</div>
  <div>2013</div>
  <div>2014</div>
  <div>2015</div>
  <div>2016</div>
  <div>2017</div>
</div>
```